# mysql sharding case study link or paper

Tags: mysql, sharding

I have been going through the book "High performance mysql", its really a nice book. But the only concern for myself is the MySQL sharding part. Even though there are a lot of theories but the practical implementation is lacking and some of the aspects are also like blackbox (arranging shrds on node). It would be great if somebody can point me to some case study article or paper so that i can under it properly.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one [link] (http://tumblr.github.com/assets/2011-11-massively_sharded_mysql.pdf). please share more if somebody has. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "sharding" is rather a design/development pattern... It's not a database feature of any kind, I would call it "it's like the database had outsourced the scale-out capability to the application".

I work for ScaleBase (http://www.scalebase.com), which is a maker of a complete scale-out solution an "automatic sharding machine" if you like, analyzes the data and SQL stream, splits the data across DB nodes, load-balances reads, and aggregates results in runtime – so you won’t have to!
No code changes, everything continues to work with “1 database”. Your application or any other client tool (mysql, mysqldump, PHPMyAdmin...) connects to ScaleBase controller (looks and feels like a MySQL), which is a proxy to a grid of "shards", automating command routing and parallelizing cross-db queries, and merge results – exactly as if the result came from 1 database. ORDER, GROUP, LIMIT, agg functions supported!

Also, please visit my blog, [http://database-scalability.blogspot.com/](http://database-scalability.blogspot.com), all about scalability...

ScaleBase my company had a webinar not so long ago, specifically about sharding and data distribution. Amazingly it's not (yet?) in the http://www.scalebase.com/resources/webinars/. I'll see if they can upload it, or I'll have the slides attached here, or similar. Stay tuned!

Hope I helped...

Doron